# Integrating Joomla 2.5 with Google Maps

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm a first time user with Joomla 2.5 . I was looking into integrating Google Maps into my website wherein a logged in user can "Create" his route information and save it, so that all the routes created by users can be displayed in a maps page.. is there a way i can do this by using extensions or plugins?

Something similar to what mapmyride does.. Is there any good known module or extensions?

thanks for any help in this regard

Answer (score 1):

There are several good extensions that we looked at awhile back, including [SimpleRoute](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/map-directions/5569), or a number of others in the [Extensions library](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/map-directions).